# Why doesn't the following stored procedure compile with MySQL Workbench version 6.3.?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I would like to know how to make the following stored procedure compile with MySQL Workbench version 6.3.

```
use puppy;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetSystemLicensing
(
    IN  _licenseName varchar(128)
)
BEGIN

IF (TRIM(_licenseName) = '')
    select * from SystemLicensing; 
ELSE
    select * from SystemLicensing where LicenseName=_licenseName;
END IF;

END
```

Here is my MySQL Workbench error message:

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select * from SystemLicensing' at line 8

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just missing the keyword `THEN`. Read more about the correct syntax [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/if.html).

Try it like this:

```
use puppy;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetSystemLicensing
(
    IN  _licenseName varchar(128)
)
BEGIN

IF (TRIM(_licenseName) = '') THEN
    select * from SystemLicensing; 
ELSE
    select * from SystemLicensing where LicenseName=_licenseName;
END IF;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: @tomborn, How could I reach you in the near future about MySQL technical questions? Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. When you post questions here, you usually get help. In the rare case, that noone answers, you can offer a bounty on your question. Then you will get an answer for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I used the MySQL set theory operator UNION ALL to make the MySql stored procedure compile.

```
use puppy;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetSystemLicensing
(
    IN  arg char(128)
)
BEGIN
   SELECT * from SystemLicensing WHERE TRIM(arg) = ' '
   UNION ALL
   SELECT  * from SystemLicensing where LicenseName = arg;
END //
```

Please leave a comment if you would like to talk through a MySQL Or Oracle question with me.

Answer (score 0):

```
use puppy;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetSystemLicensing
(
    IN  _licenseName varchar(128)
)
BEGIN

IF (TRIM(_licenseName) = '') THEN
    select * from SystemLicensing; 
ELSE
    select * from SystemLicensing where LicenseName=_licenseName;
END IF;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```